# UIImageView's CALayer's anchorPoint "accessing unknown component of property" error

Tags: iphone, calayer, quartz-2d

I'm trying to rotate an image about the bottom right corner. To do this I know I need to set the layer's anchorPoint, but I can't access it. I've included the QuartzCore framework in my project. To simplify the problem as much as possible, I've reduced the method to these three lines, which still throw the error "error: accessing unknown 'anchorPoint' component of a property" (line 2).

```
UIView *sqView = [[UIView alloc] init];
sqView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
[sqView release];
```

It must be something truly stupid. I've looked at other examples of this and they appear identical. What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

have you added

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```